# Need help parallelizing this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, joblib

I ran into a pickle (literally) in parallelizing the following Python code and could really need some help.

First of all the input is a CSV file consisting of a list of website links that I need to scrape with the function `scrape_function()`. The original code is as follows and runs perfectly

```
with open('C:\\links.csv','r') as source:
    reader=csv.reader(source)
    inputlist=list(reader)

m=[]

for i in inputlist:
    m.append(scrape_code(re.sub("\'|\[|\]",'',str(i)))) #remove the quotes around the link strings otherwise it results in URLError

print(m)
```

I then tried to parallelize this code using `joblib` as follows:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

with open('C:\\links.csv','r') as source:
        reader=csv.reader(source)
        inputlist=list(reader)

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
results = Parallel(n_jobs=cores)(delayed(m.append(scrape_code(re.sub("\'|\[|\]",'',str(i))))) for i in inputlist)
```

However, this would result in a weird error:

```
  File "C:\Users\...\joblib\pool.py", line 371, in send
    CustomizablePickler(buffer, self._reducers).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'delayed.<locals>.delayed_function'
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? If I try to put the append in a separate function like below then the error would go away, but the execution would then freeze and hang indefinitely:

```
def process(k):
    a=[]
    a.append(scrape_code(re.sub("\'|\[|\]",'',str(k))))
    return a

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
results = Parallel(n_jobs=cores)(delayed(process)(i) for i in inputlist)
```

The input list has 10000s of pages so parallel processing would be a huge benefit.

Comment: I know nothing about joblib so I can't help, but why not just stick with the multiprocessing library?

Comment: What's wrong with using the built-in [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module? That being said, the majority of time here will be spent on network I/O so instead of dealing with shared memory and context switching just use regular threads to do your bidding - it's very likely they'll end up faster than multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it in separate processes, the easiest way is to just create a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and let it deal with distributing the links to your function, e.g.:

```
import csv
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":  # multiprocessing guard
    with open("c:\\links.csv", "r", newline="") as f:  # open the CSV
        reader = csv.reader(f)  # create a reader
        links = [r[0] for r in reader]  # collect only the first column
    with Pool() as pool:  # create a pool, it will make a pool with all your CPU cores...
        results = pool.map(scrape_code, links)  # distribute your links to scrape_code
    print(results)
```

NOTE: I'm assuming your `links.csv` actually holds the link in its first column based on how you're pre-processing the links in your code.

However, as I've stated in my comment, this doesn't have to be necessarily faster than plain threading so I'd first try it using threads. Fortunately, the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module includes a [threading interfrace dummy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) so you just need to replace `from multiprocessing import Pool` with `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` and see in what regime your code works faster.